# email delivery - ms outlook set up

Tags: ms-office

I recently purchased a 15" MBP.
The unit is set up and fully operational, but I am uncertain about Outlook set up.
I have MS Outlook '11 installed with 3 POP accounts created and receive mail into the inbox folder.

I have imported my old .pst files from my Windows PC and those folders appear below the inbox.

I would like emails to be automatically delivered to the relevant folder for that account and not all collectively in the inbox.

Is there any way of setting this up?

Answer (score 1):

This should happen automatically and no special setup is required. Click on the email account's inbox (on the left side of the window) that you would like to see just that inbox. This should pull up the inbox for that account only.